# How to Add an image in the center of an Atomic shape in jointJS-Rappid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jointjs, rappid

Is there any way I can add an image in the center of an Atomic shape which has 3 in-ports and 3 out-ports?

I don't want a solution exclusively for an Atomic shape. It could be a custom shape but in case of a custom shape I want it to have in-ports and out-ports.

My so far code (without adding this  image) is:

```
new joint.shapes.devs.Atomic({
            size: { width: 4, height: 3 },
            inPorts: ['in1','in2','in3'],
            outPorts: ['out1','out2','out3'],
            attrs: {
        rect: { fill: '#ffffff', rx: 2, ry: 2 },
 text: { text: 'Workitem', fill: '#000000', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 },
        '.inPorts circle': { fill: '#dddddd', opacity: 0.9 },
            '.outPorts circle': { fill: '#dddddd', opacity: 0.9 },
        '.inPorts text, .outPorts text': { 'font-size': 9 }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a very complex solution but finally I came up with the following code which works great and it's stable:

```
/*Code to create a new Workitem Shape with an image inside it*/
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: $('#paper'),
  width: 600,
  height: 600,
  gridSize: 20,
  model: graph
});

joint.shapes.devs.MyImageModel = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend({

  markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect class="body"/></g><image/><text class="label"/><g class="inPorts"/><g class="outPorts"/></g>',

  defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({

    type: 'devs.MyImageModel',
    size: {
      width: 80,
      height: 80
    },
    attrs: {
      rect: {
        stroke: '#d1d1d1',
        fill: {
          type: 'linearGradient',
          stops: [{
            offset: '0%',
            color: 'white'
          }, {
            offset: '50%',
            color: '#d1d1d1'
          }],
          attrs: {
            x1: '0%',
            y1: '0%',
            x2: '0%',
            y2: '100%'
          }
        }
      },
      circle: {
        stroke: 'gray'
      },
      '.label': {
        text: 'My Workitem',
        'ref-y': +65,
        'font-size': 14
      },
      '.inPorts circle': {
        fill: '#dddddd', opacity: 0.9
      },
      '.outPorts circle': {
        fill: '#dddddd', opacity: 0.9
      },
      '.inPorts text, .outPorts text': { 'font-size': 9 },
      image: {
        'xlink:href': 'img/person.png',
        width: 80,
        height: 50,
        'ref-x': .5,
        'ref-y': .5,
        ref: 'rect',
        'x-alignment': 'middle',
        'y-alignment': 'middle'
      }
    }

  }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
});

joint.shapes.devs.MyImageModelView = joint.shapes.devs.ModelView;

// Usage:

var imageModel = new joint.shapes.devs.MyImageModel({
  position: {
    x: 200,
    y: 250
  },
  size: {
    width: 150,
    height: 100
  },
  inPorts: ['in1', 'in2','in3'],
  outPorts: ['out1', 'out2', 'out3']
});

graph.addCell(imageModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

please try the below, i added an image to the attrs {} The image attribute works for joint.shapes.basic.device. Hoping it works for Atomic as well.

```
new joint.shapes.devs.Atomic({
            size: { width: 4, height: 3 },
            inPorts: ['in1','in2','in3'],
            outPorts: ['out1','out2','out3'],
            attrs: {
        rect: { fill: '#ffffff', rx: 2, ry: 2 },
        image: { xlink:href: '/path to image' },

 text: { text: 'Workitem', fill: '#000000', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 },
        '.inPorts circle': { fill: '#dddddd', opacity: 0.9 },
            '.outPorts circle': { fill: '#dddddd', opacity: 0.9 },
        '.inPorts text, .outPorts text': { 'font-size': 9 }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work in my case. Atomic has different attributes than a basic shape and unfortunately it's more complex.